# Scrabblecheater in Java: How to correctly write to a nested ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, hashtable

We have to write a basic program, that is supposed to read a wordlist from a file, find permutations of the words, and stores all the words that have the same normalized version together in one chain. the normalized version always lays on top of the chain. 
The normalized word should be used as the index key, while the permutations of the word should be returned as an array of strings in the given hsah location.

We tried to implement the storing of the index key, and the permutations by using a nested ArrayList.

```
 private File testfile = new File("wordlist.txt");
 private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>[] table;
 int entries = 0;

 public Dictionary(int size) {
  table = new ArrayList[size];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   table[i] = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(99);
 }

 public void newDictionary() {
  for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++)
   table[i] = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(99);
 }
```

our hash function looks like this:

```
    public void hash(String word) {

  word = word.toLowerCase();
  String id = normalize(word);
  int hashValue = 0;
  char[] chars = word.toCharArray();

  for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
   int e = chars[i] - 97;
   hashValue += e * 26 ^ i;
  }

  if (hashValue < 0)
   hashValue = hashValue * (-1);
  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> chain = table[hashValue];


  boolean newList = true;
  boolean cB = chain.isEmpty();

  if (chain.size() > 0) {
   for (int i = 0; i < chain.size(); i++) {
    ArrayList<String> currentChain = chain.get(i);

    try {
     String a = currentChain.get(0);
     System.out.println(a);
    } catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("ERROR!");
    }

   }
  }
  if (newList == true || chain.size() == 0) {
   chain.add(new ArrayList<String>());
   chain.get(0).add(0, id);
   chain.get(0).add(word);
  }
 }
```

We assumed that we properly implemented the nested ArrayList, but when trying to access `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> chain = table[hashValue];`, e.g. by invoking `boolean cB = chain.isEmpty();`, our program crashes.

Apart from that, we are not able to print out all of the values at index 0 within our `currentChain`. 
We surrounded the respective print-method with a try-catch block, otherwise our program would crash; now, our program runs, but rarely outputs a String, and rather throws an Exception when running the print-method:

```
 try {
     String a = currentChain.get(0);
     System.out.println(a);
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The stacktrace outputs the following error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
    at Dictionary.hash(Dictionary.java:78)
    at Dictionary.readFromFile(Dictionary.java:32)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

We are quite confused about the following `Index: 0, Size: 0`

Did we correctly implement the nested `ArrayList`s? 
What could be the reason for us to not being able to correctly store our Strings within our ArrayList most of the time?

Comment: That's a really terrible way to implement exception "handling". You are making things harder for yourself by adding those useless try/catch blocks. If you insist on adding them then you should *at least* print the stacktrace. But it's a much better idea to *not* catch exceptions you can't do something useful with.

Comment: Stacktrace might be a good idea, thx

Comment: ok, I added the output of the stacktrace.

Comment: The exception tells you that you are trying to access the first element (the one at index 0) of an empty list (size 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fix your code then you need to know that the elements of an array list are when not initialized.

Change the constructor and `newDictionary()` method as such:

```
  public Dictionary(int size) {
        //noinspection unchecked
        table = new ArrayList[size];

        newDictionary();
    }

    public void newDictionary() {
        for (int i = 0; i < table.length ; i++) {
            table[i] = new ArrayList<List<String>>(99);

            for ( int j = 0; j < 99; j++ ) {
                table[i].add(new ArrayList<String>());
            }
        }
    }
```

i would also change the declaration of the table member to:

```
private List<List<String>>[] table;
```

which means to also update the decalration of the chain variable from the hash method to this

```
List<List<String>> chain = table[hashValue];
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

[Mutimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) is the data structure you are looking for.

> A collection similar to a Map, but
>   which may associate multiple values
>   with a single key. If you call put(K,
>   V) twice, with the same key but
>   different values, the multimap
>   contains mappings from the key to both
>   values.